# Is there a way to tell if this object is an eloquent object or not?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to generalize turning arrays into json and it's getting a little messed up when I added eloquent models into the mix.

Is there a way to tell if this object is an eloquent object or not?

Like an isEloquent() function or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

or you can use this

```
 $isEloquent = ($yourObject instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function is_subclass_of

```
$isEloquent = is_subclass_of($yourObject, 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');
```